# How to Create Custom World in Stage

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Stage tutorial about creating custom world in Stage, there is no specified tutorial about creating a custom world based on image file. I want to make my own world file based on a circular robot, can anyone help me with how to write my own world file with all the necessary parameters, and how to define a simulated laser sensor in the world file? By the way, I'm using ROS Fuerte.
Your help is most appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58261/how-to-create-custom-world-in-stage/) by [Andre Setiawan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4435/andre-setiawan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm writing the tutorial, but I haven't finished it yet... Take a look on this [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z9a7_pUjAzffjLQwJS3TbPZKW0F-7FDCU_35fqv-Ycs/edit?usp=sharing) and if you need something else let me know. All sugestions will be well recieved.

Gustavo.

**EDIT 1:**

Currently stage in ROS just support one ranger model for each position model (robot), when the laser element is defined within robot definition, pose attribute set the position of laser in the robot. There is a patch for supporting various lasers in a single robot, you can use it or if you want, you can modify stageros node or create your custom simulator based on it.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andre Setiawan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4435/andre-setiawan/) on 2013-03-16**:
Thank you for the reply. Can you elaborate more about the parameters specified under the sensor specification (Range, FOV, Samples)? Does the sensor's points indicate the location of each laser sensor?